# Test Strategy for a Data Centre Move

Tags: test-planning, test-strategy, data

I'm looking for a good example of a Test Strategy for a Data Centre Move.

My company is physically moving locations. This means that our IT Systems will need to be migrated as part of physical servers moves or the IT Systems will need to be migrated to the cloud.

So I'm looking for a good example of a Test Strategy we can use for our move.

Comment: This is a question about a one time effort, it's belongs to IT/devops or other communities. On top of that (although fixable through editing) the question is much too broad and lacks details

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't understand why a Test Strategy would not be suitable here. Could you please explain this more?

Comment: I see the question you have asked as related to the activity of network engineering or IT specialists, my view of this SE is of questions related to ongoing quality ans test activities. Yes, some test tasks are done only once but still as part of a quality process and goal.

Comment: I see that it may apply to some organisations but in others this entire activity i.e. creating a Test Strategy will be the responsibility of a Test Manager. I thought fundamentally a Test Strategy would be seen as a QA exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://www.planittesting.com/au/Insights/2016/What-are-the-Challenges-of-Testing-a-Data-Centre-M

It provides a really good starting point.